# SQL Server count entries in one table against another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two temporary tables in SQL Server 2008

Table 1, results_types

```
------------
| Result_1 |
| Result_2 |
| Result_3 |
| Result_N |
------------
```

Table 2, all_results

```
--------------------
| Run_A | Result_1 |
| Run_A | Result_2 |
| Run_B | Result_3 |
| Run_B | Result_3 |
| Run_B | Result_3 |
| Run_B | Result_3 |
| Run_C | Result_2 |
--------------------
```

How can I make a query that returns a summary which counts each entry in *results_types* without iterating through *results_types* please.
Thanks in advance

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| 'Run' | Result_1 | Result_2 | Result_3 | Result_N |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Run_A | 1        | 2        | 0        | 0        |
| Run_B | 0        | 0        | 4        | 0        |
| Run_C | 0        | 2        | 0        | 0        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SQL-server Pivot function and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((   SELECT  ',' + Result_Type
                                        FROM    Result_Types
                                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '  SELECT  *
                                FROM    all_results
                                        PIVOT
                                        (   COUNT(Result_Type)
                                            FOR Result_Type IN (' + @Cols + ')
                                        ) pvt;'
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a7a2/3)**

Comment: Thanks - I was using the pivot but didn't want to have to iterate through every result_type.

Comment: @SkeetJon: If the result_type set is fixed, though, it's better to list them explicitly, thus avoiding dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Andriy M: It is fixed but there are just over 100 result_types. Would you advocate typing them all out or using dynamic SQL for best performance

Comment: Typing them out. You could use the code above to generate the SQL once, then use that static SQL. In my opinion Dynamic SQL is best avoided, it does have its use, but if something can be achieved without dynamic SQL then it should be.

Comment: @SkeetJon: If we are talking about the database system's performance then yes, I would. A certain, even if unnoticeable, amount of time would need to be spent every time on the generation of the SQL, afterwards it might or might not be same as with the static query. However, I think it is a good idea by Gareth to use this script to generate the final query *once*, then use and maintain the resulting query as a static one.